# Tomcat 8.0.51 - 20 Extra Seconds to Start For Unknown Reason

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I just upgraded from Tomcat 8.0.32 to 8.0.51. I'm noticing that it is doing something (or stuck) for 20 seconds for some unknown reason... Here's a snippet of the log...

```
17-Apr-2018 00:04:23.711 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 532 ms
17-Apr-2018 00:04:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
17-Apr-2018 00:04:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.51
17-Apr-2018 00:04:26.620 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal No SingleSignOn Valve is present

[WHY THE DELAY HERE?]

17-Apr-2018 00:04:47.140 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name Administrator used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
17-Apr-2018 00:04:47.150 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal No SingleSignOn Valve is present
```

After that the logging for my webapp starts. I have yanked all the logging up to FINE but there doesn't appear to be a reason for the delay? I've disabled the TLD Scanner. I looked at the urandom issue I found but that seems to only be an issue prior to Java 8 (I'm running Java 1.8.0_74) and I don't see any logging to support that it could be the issue.

Any suggestions on what may be causing this delay? It just seems to go off into the weeds for 20 seconds.

Comment: Are you using TLS/SSL? Does it always wait 20 seconds, or sometimes is it a longer or shorter delay? During the delay, take a thread dump to see what's happening.

Comment: No TLS or SSL. Ah good idea about the thread dump. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on what may be causing this delay?

A connection timeout, run `netstat -an` and look for `SYN_SENT` connections.
You should pay attention to these messages about authentication.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I don't see anything out of the ordinary. I have since upgraded to 8.5.30 and it seems to run much better. There's only about a 5 second delay... In terms of the security warnings... I was curious about that as well. I have security setup for all servlets but I'm overriding it in a couple of servlets with annotations. I'm wondering if this is why it's complaining? Even though everything is covered as I have tested each servlet. Is it because of this override?

Comment: I didn't ask if you see anything unusual, but if you have SYN_SENT connections ;) Or maybe your Tomcat and database (or LDAP, or Active Directory) are on the same server ? You should tell us if you're running on Windows or Linux.